# Pop-up message breaking CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following C# to create a pop-up error message when data is not fully inputted and a button is pressed:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Error Message')", true);
```

The pop-up is working, however, it appears to be breaking the CSS of the page.

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the button in javascript instead of ASP.net